# Searching for a string in database

Tags: database, parse-platform

We are using `Parse` as data base but this question is in general .

In the data base we have a column called `text`, this column can have a long text in it (400-500 words)

`Parse` (the data base) is letting you to search for strings that may appear in a columns.

We are using it to search for a string in the `text` column , and we get all the results where that column contains that string.

```
 PFQuery *getRelevantRows=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Data"]; //table name
    [getRelevantRows whereKey:@"text" containsString:@"Car"]; //column
```

Question is , when the data base will have **million rows** , and many users, and they all will search for words in the data base,in the same manner , is it healthy for the DB ?
Is there another way to do so , *without* setting keywords in the `DB` ?

Is that approach is common ? (after all ,they gives you that possibility )

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend reading this blog post on the Parse blog:

http://blog.parse.com/2014/04/01/smart-indexing-at-parse/

You also need to be aware that string matching is Case-Sensitive, searching for "Car" wont find rows that have "car". It is common to create a before-save handler that creates a copy of the field in lowercase and then to make sure all searches also convert the input to lowercase.

The keywords approach is used commonly also, I'm not sure how well either one will perform so perhaps others will be able to chime in from a performance perspective.